# AFrame Video primitive no longer renders when canvas is used as a src

Tags: canvas, video, textures, aframe, src

Version 0.8.2 allowed you to use a canvas id as the src of a video primitive. In Version 1.0.4, when you use a canvas id as a video src, the element doesn't render and there is no warning or error message.

```
A-Frame Version: 1.0.4
Platform / Device: Windows 10 Firefox 78.0.2, Chrome 84.0.4147.89
Reproducible Code Snippet or URL: https://codepen.io/azmartone/pen/JjGqvzq
```

In the codepen, switch the aframe.min.js versions and you will see that it works for 0.8.2 and not 1.0.4

Does anyone know if there were intentional updates regarding canvas texture on video primitives?

Answer (score 2):

In earlier versions, canvas elements were loaded as THREE.VideoTexture and AFrame had a RAF step to update the texture. Since 0.9.0, canvas elements are now loaded as THREE.CanvasTexture with no repeating texture update.

However, we can use the canvas-updater component to achieve dynamic canvas textures

https://github.com/aframevr/aframe/issues/4659

canvas-updater
https://github.com/aframevr/aframe/blob/4a44a804bbf7347e41fdc88daa6fa1d68756029d/examples/test/canvas-texture/components/canvas-updater.js

Answer (score 0):

example code implementing a variation of canvas-updater style code: https://glitch.com/edit/#!/live-canvas-demo?path=index.html%3A54%3A29

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="https://aframe.io/releases/1.2.0/aframe.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <script>
    AFRAME.registerComponent('live-canvas', {
      dependencies: ['geometry', 'material'],
      schema: {
        src: { type: "string", default: "#id"}
      },
      init() {
        if (!document.querySelector(this.data.src)) {
          console.error("no such canvas")
          return
        }
        this.el.setAttribute('material', 'src', this.data.src);
        this.tick = AFRAME.utils.throttleTick(this.tick, 1000 / 60, this);
      },
      tick() {
        var material;

        material = this.el.getObject3D('mesh').material;
        if (!material.map) {
          console.error("no material map");
          this.el.removeAttribute('live-canvas');
          return;
        }
        material.map.needsUpdate = true;
      }
    });
  </script>
  <body>
    <div id="container"></div>
    <a-scene>
      <a-assets>
        <!-- texture sizes should be powers of 2 -->
        <img id="img1" crossorigin="anonymous" src="https://cdn.glitch.com/152a8c29-52c1-464c-bf9a-4f233815b8ab%2Fdoge-1.jpg?v=1632301952345"/>
        <img id="img2" crossorigin="anonymous" src="https://cdn.glitch.com/152a8c29-52c1-464c-bf9a-4f233815b8ab%2Fdoge-2.jpg?v=1632301954299"/>
        <canvas crossorigin="anonymous" id="mycanvas" width="512" height="512"></canvas>
      </a-assets>
      <a-sky color="#01B5FE"></a-sky>

      <a-plane
        side="double"
        width="6"
        height="6"
        position="0 5 -10"
        material="shader: flat;"
        live-canvas="src:#mycanvas;"
        animation="property: rotation; to: 0 360 0; loop: true; dur: 10000"
      >
      </a-plane>
      <a-box position="0 5 -10" live-canvas="src:#mycanvas;"></a-box>
    </a-scene>
  </body>

  <script>
    // make a canvas that updates regularly
    const canvas = document.getElementById("mycanvas"),
        ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

    canvas.width = 512;
    canvas.height = 512;

    let frames = [
      document.getElementById("img1"),
      document.getElementById("img2"),
    ]

    let i = 0;
    setInterval(() => {
      i = (i === 0 ? 1 : 0);
      console.log("canvas update")
      ctx.drawImage(frames[i],0,0); 
    },1000)
  </script>
</html>
```